# Nested controllers and functions - return value undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a main controller that contains an xhr function, like this

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.xhr = function(requestData) {

        var ajax = "/ajax/";

        $http({ url: ajax, data: requestData, method: 'POST' })
        .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data); // data shows up in the console,, but after the undefined from directive controller
                return data;
        })
        .error(function(err){"ERR", console.log(err)});
    }

}]);
```

Then I have a directive that uses the xhr function from main controller in it's own controller,, like so

```
app.directive("register", function ($http) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        $scope.register = {};
        $scope.request = {};
        $scope.response = {};

            $scope.createAccount = function () {

                $scope.request= {
                    action: "register",
                    data: $scope.register
                }

                $scope.response = $scope.xhr($scope.request);
                console.log($scope.response);
            }
    },
    templateUrl: "register.html"
}
});
```

When I trigger the **$scope.createAccount** function in directive controller, the return value is undefined. I am unable to figure out why. It feels like there is something obvious that I am missing.

Comment: you are logging `responseData` but assigning value to `response` ?

Comment: that is a typo I will correct,, in the actual code it is correct

Answer (score 1):

The `$http` service returns a promise, and you are assigning a value to `$scope.response` before verifying the promise has resolved. This means that it is undefined at the time of declaration.

In your `xhr` method, you should return the `$http` call. Then, in your directive:

```
$scope.xhr($scope.request).then(function(data){ 
  $scope.response = data; 
});
```

Comment: Hm,, I sort of understand.. Working on it.